# how do i upgrade my custom eks nodegroup version using cdk?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks, aws-cdk

I am trying to upgrade my EKS cluster version and node group version via CDK.

For EKS cluster version, I bumped the version for the eks cluster in cdk.

```js
this.cluster = new eks.Cluster(this, 'eks-cluster', {
  vpc: props.vpc,
  clusterName: props.clusterName,
  version: eks.KubernetesVersion.V1_22,
});
```

This change deployed successfully and I can observe the cluster version have been updated (v1.22). However, the node group version did not get updated (v1.21).

[image: eks cluster version]
[image: node group version]

I was only able to find doc to upgrade node group version using `eksctl` or `aws console`, but these are manual and I would have to do it for each node group.

reference doc - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/update-managed-node-group.html

How can I upgrade my node group version using cdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `releaseVersion` in `NodegroupProps` to specify the EKS version.

The string for `releaseVersion` is in the form of `k8s_major_version.k8s_minor_version.k8s_patch_version-release_date` according to [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eks-linux-ami-versions.html). The list of AMI version is found in the [changelogs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eks-linux-ami-versions.html).

```js
const nodeGroup = new eks.Nodegroup(this, 'myNodeGroup', {
  cluster: this.cluster,
  forceUpdate: false,
  amiType: eks.NodegroupAmiType.AL2_X86_64,
  releaseVersion: '<AMI ID obtained from changelog>',
  capacityType: eks.CapacityType.ON_DEMAND,
  desiredSize: 5,
});
```