# how do i upgrade eks default nodegroup version using cdk?

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-cdk

Please note this question is a different question than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74816376/how-do-i-upgrade-my-custom-eks-nodegroup-version-using-cdk). The custom eks node group is defined by me and exposes configurations for me to modify. This question is specifically regarding the default node group, which lack any `props` or exposed configuration for me to modify.

I would like to upgrade the default node group that was created by CDK when I provisioned the EKS cluster.

```js
this.cluster = new eks.Cluster(this, 'eks-cluster', {
  vpc: props.vpc,
  clusterName: props.clusterName,
  version: eks.KubernetesVersion.V1_22,
  albController: {
    version: eks.AlbControllerVersion.V2_4_1,
  },
  defaultCapacity: 5,
});
```

However, I do not see any options to modify the version for the default node group. I have already bump the cluster version to v1.22 as well as my custom node groups, but the default node group still uses v1.21.

[image: eks-default-node-group-version]

How can I upgrade the default node group version using CDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experiments and observations, there is nothing special with the [default node group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_eks.Cluster.html#defaultnodegroup) that EKS creates, `this.cluster.defaultNodegroup`. It is just a typical EKS node group with auto-scaling and no taints. I created my own default node group and used a updated AMI release version.

I disabled the defaultCapacity and set it to 0, and then created my own custom node group with same configurations as the one EKS created by default.

```js
this.cluster = new eks.Cluster(this, 'eks-cluster', {
  vpc: props.vpc,
  clusterName: props.clusterName,
  version: eks.KubernetesVersion.V1_23,
  kubectlLayer: new KubectlV23Layer(this, 'kubectl'),
  albController: {
    version: eks.AlbControllerVersion.V2_4_1,
  },
  // set this to 0 to disable default node group created by EKS
  defaultCapacity: 0, 
});

const defaultNodeGroup = new eks.Nodegroup(this, 'default-node-group', {
  cluster: this.cluster,
  releaseVersion: '<updated AMI release version>',
  nodegroupName: 'eks-default-nodegroup',
});
```

[image: eks_default_node_group_upgraded]